# Want to customize install option using live build in linux

Tags: linux, iso, live-build

Using live build tool to create ISO image. Want to customize the install wizard to provide more flexibility for ISO installation. Any idea which files we need to edit for this or how to approach for the customization.

Comment: this depends a lot on the kind of system you're basing your live image on. Different Linux distros have different ways, different tools to build live images.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am using using Linux build-11 5.10.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.127-1 (2022-06-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: so, this is a debian system?

Comment: yes it is debian 11 from the comments.